# parsing json with swift confusion (beginner to swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hello am trying to get the values of start_date, end_date, section, instructors and location, but i can only get the section from this JSON:

```
"data":[
 {
  "subject":"CS",
  "catalog_number":"135",
  "units":0.5,
  "title":"Designing Functional Programs",
  "note":"Choose TUT section for Related 1.",
  "class_number":6248,
  "section":"LEC 001",
  "campus":"UW U",
  "associated_class":1,
  "related_component_1":null,
  "related_component_2":"201",
  "enrollment_capacity":90,
  "enrollment_total":74,
  "waiting_capacity":0,
  "waiting_total":0,
  "topic":null,
  "reserves":[
    {
      "reserve_group":"Year 1 students ",
      "enrollment_capacity":82,
      "enrollment_total":66
    }
  ],
  "classes":[
    {
      "date":{
        "start_time":"10:00",
        "end_time":"11:20",
        "weekdays":"TTh",
        "start_date":null,
        "end_date":null,
        "is_tba":false,
        "is_cancelled":false,
        "is_closed":false
      },
      "location":{
        "building":"PHY",
        "room":"150"
      },
      "instructors":[
        "Tompkins,Dave"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "held_with":[

  ],
  "term":1159,
  "academic_level":"undergraduate",
  "last_updated":"2015-12-29T01:01:51-05:00"
},
```

with this code;

```
import UIKit
var objects: [AnyObject] = []

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
        for data in json["data"].arrayValue {
            let sec = data["section"].stringValue
            let start = data["classes"]["date"]["start_time"].stringValue
            let end = data["classes"]["date"]["end_time"].stringValue
            let inst = data["classes"]["instructors"].stringValue
            let loc = data["classes"]["location"]["building"].stringValue
            let obj = ["sec": sec, "start": start, "end": end, "inst": inst,"loc": loc]
            objects.append(obj)

        }

    }


    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "https://api.uwaterloo.ca/v2/courses/CS/135/schedule.json?key="API_key"

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
            let json = JSON(data: data)

            if json["meta"]["status"].intValue == 200 {
                parseJSON(json)
                print(objects)
            }
        }
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


}
```

And i have a follow up, how can i represent the data the i get from the request on a table.

Comment: `classes` is an array like `data` represented by the brackets `[]`

Comment: but isn't classes inside data?

Comment: why ur `parseJSON` function is in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: yes, but you need something like `data["classes"][0]["date"]`

Comment: @aaisataev i did it to check how everything works on the console before i make the actual app.

Comment: @vadian can you please explain to me what [0] is doing here?

Comment: Dictionaries are subscripted by key `["key"]`, arrays by index `[0]`

Comment: I ill post a better way to do it give me some time

Answer (score 0):

which json format are you using ?? Apple JSON(NSJSONSerialization), JSONKit,TouchJson,jsonframework ??

if you use NSJSONSerialization, the method like this.

```
let urlget = NSURL(string:"yourlink")
NSLog("this is urlget \(urlget)")
let Data = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlget!)
var jsonData = NSDictionary()
do {
jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(Data!,options:[] ) as! NSDictionary
}
catch{
}
NSLog("this is getData\(jsonData)")
```

if other, please see this links!

JSONKit
https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

TouchJSON
https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

JSONFramework
https://github.com/mineshpurohit/JSONFramework

Answer (score -1):

You may use following code to extract your suggested keys.

In following code, the variable 
**dictJson** is the dictionary converted from json string.

```
let dictJson = convertStringToDictionary(strJson as String) // dictJson is a dictionary
        let dictValue = dictJson["data"]!       // dictValue variable is an array

        // Classes is an array and the date is dictionary in the array
        print("weekdays -> \(dictValue![0]["classes"]!![0]["date"]!!["weekdays"]!!)")   //
        print("start_date -> \(dictValue![0]["classes"]!![0]["date"]!!["start_date"]!!)")
        print("end_date -> \(dictValue![0]["classes"]!![0]["date"]!!["end_date"]!!)")
        print("section -> \(dictValue![0]["section"]!!)")
        // Now if you want to explore the array "instructors", you will have to do the same as I did with "classes"
        print("instructors -> \(dictValue![0]["classes"]!![0]["instructors"]!!)")   //
        print("location -> \(dictValue![0]["classes"]!![0]["location"]!!)")   //
```

You may get the full code (playground code) at 
http://pastebin.com/aMqXrUsK